# C++: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘!’ token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've read most of the relevant answers on this topic already, but I can't seem to find anything wrong with my code.  Below is my code:

oneaborq.cc

```
...
#include "stdmacro.h"
...

class marker_t {
public:
   signed_city_id_t val;
   inline marker_t() { val = 0; };
   inline signed_city_id_t is_true() { return val; };
   inline signed_city_id_t is_false() { return (signed_city_id_t)!val; };
   inline void make_true() { val = 1; };
   inline void not() { val = (signed_city_id_t)!val; };
};
```

stdmacro.h

```
#define LARGE_CITY_ID
...
typedef
#ifdef UNSIGNED_CITY_ID
unsigned
#else
signed
#endif
#ifdef LARGE_CITY_ID
short
#else
char
#endif
city_id_t;

/* signed_city_id_t is the same sizeof() as the city_id_t but can be negative
 * and should be asserted not to go more than positive MAX_DEGREE/2
 */
typedef
signed
#ifdef LARGE_CITY_ID
short
#else
char
#endif
signed_city_id_t;
```

I've tried changing "signed_city_id_t" to be explicitly "short" or "int" in oneaborq.cc, but that didn't seem to help.  I've also tried just changing the entire class definition to:

```
class marker_t {
public:
   int val;
   inline marker_t() { val = 0; };
   inline int is_true() { return 0; };
   inline int is_false() { return 0; };
   inline void make_true() { val = 1; };
   inline void not() { val = 0; };
};
```

Even when there is no "!" in the entire class definition, it still gets the same error: 
"oneaborq.cc:207: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘!’ token"

I'm trying to compile a TSP (Travelins Salesman Problem) solver (found here: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/tsp/distrib/tsp_solve) on OS X, so if anybody wants to see the entire source code, take a look at the link above.

Comment: One issue is that marker_t() does not have a return type.

Comment: Surprised that the `is_*` functions don't return `bool`. And what is `(signed_city_id_t)!val` supposed to accomplish anyway? `!` gives a `bool` (or at least `bool`-like) result and changing it to a city ID seems silly. Also, `"stdmacro.h"` looks obfuscated; why not use a templated type for the city ID?

Comment: @rerun: `marker_t()` is the constructor. It is not allowed a return type.

Comment: Opps yea I thought it was another function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
inline void not() { val = (signed_city_id_t)!val; };
```

`not` is like a keyword in C++ and is an alternative spelling for the `!` token. You cannot use it as the name of a function.

Comment: "like a keyword" == reserved word?

Comment: yes they are reserved words. technically they are not keywords but pretty much like them.

Comment: Just making sure "reserved word" still meant something and the standard didn't deprecate it or drop it and start using "like a keyword".